# Dynamic tag based on build number in Openshift buildconfig

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

I am doing CI/CD using openshift buildconfig. I am able to fetch the source code from git and successfully build the docker image and push to internal registry. I want to tag the image built with with build numbers based on Openshift Build config output labels are annotations. How to do that in the YAML, I am using docker build strategy.

```
output:
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: 'internal.registry.com/app_name/sample_app:<BUILD_NUMBER/NAME>'
```

Also once this is done, i want to update the image in deployment to get new version of app. Have anyone done such setup, Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: What CI system are you using?

Comment: Openshift Buildconfig, Docker strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The yaml file is resolved when the buildConfig is created, it can't have references to environment variables or build number information. If you are doing this from a CI/CD pipeline, you could create a different buildConfig in the same CI/CD pipeline, run it, and delete it. But you may have permissions issue to create the buildConfig every time.

Another option I would prefer is to use [ImageStreams](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.1/html/images/managing-image-streams). With ImageStream a single object keeps track of all versions of the image via sha codes, therefore there is no need to update the yaml every time.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN HAVE DYNAMIC TAG -- But it's NOT as PER YOUR naming conventions:

As per Openshift 4.11, i can see that it's possible to get dynamic tag with `DockerImage` output by not specifying a tag explicitly. You need to read the new tag from the yaml of the Build (which is an execution of a BuildConfig) under `status.output.to.imageDigest`

example:

```yaml
kind: BuildConfig
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: registry.company.lan/myproject/myapp
```

Summarizing: You can get the full name of an image which generated with a dynamic tag using this jsonpaths:

```bash
kubectl get build mybuild-N -o jsonpath='{.spec.output.to.name}{"@"}{.status.output.t
o.imageDigest}'
```